# Error: Cannot assign to '...' in 'self'

Tags: swift, initialization, uikit, init

I have this code

```
import UIKit

class SliderControllerView: UIView{
    private let type: ControlType!
    private let label: UILabel!
    private let slider: UISlider!
    private weak var delegate: SliderControllerDelegate?

    private let defaults: SliderDefaults!

    convenience init(type: ControlType, defaults: SliderDefaults, delegate: SliderControllerDelegate?) {

        self.init()

        self.type = type
        self.delegate = delegate
        self.defaults = defaults

        setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)

        label = UILabel()
        configureLabel()

        slider = UISlider()
        configureSlider(slider)

        SliderDefaults.set(slider, defaults: defaults)

        if let valueFromDetauls = userDefaultsValue {
            slider.value = Float(valueFromDetauls)
        }

        saveValueInUserDefaults()
        updateLabel()
    }
```

Error messages:

1. Cannot assign to 'type' in 'self'
2. Cannot assign to 'defaults' in 'self'
3. Cannot assign to 'label' in 'self'
4. Cannot assign to 'slider' in 'self'

What me do?
Thanks!

Comment: You meant `super.init()` right?

Comment: When I used super.init(), I get error "Must call a designated initializer of the superclass 'UIView'"

Comment: Then you should call `super.init(frame: CGRectZero)` if you don't want to set a frame. if you call `self.init()` that will call the `init` recursively over and over again

Comment: I get error: Property 'self.type' not initialized at super.init call
Immutable value 'self.type may only be initialized once
Immutable value 'self.defaults’ may only be initialized once
Immutable value 'self.label’ may only be initialized once
Immutable value 'self.slider' may only be initialized once

Comment: you should call `super.init` after all your class variables are initialised

Comment: Please show the example code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I made a couple of modifications to the code so it would compile although it does change the meaning some.

```
class SliderControllerView: UIView {

    // Converted "let" to "var"
    private var type: ControlType!
    private var label: UILabel!
    private var slider: UISlider!
    private weak var delegate: SliderControllerDelegate?

    private var defaults: SliderDefaults!

    // Added frame to init
    convenience init(frame: CGRect, type: ControlType, defaults: SliderDefaults, delegate: SliderControllerDelegate?) {

        // Call designated init(frame: CGRect) for UIView
        self.init(frame: frame)
        self.type = type
        self.delegate = delegate
        self.defaults = defaults

        setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)

        label = UILabel()
        configureLabel()

        slider = UISlider()
        configureSlider(slider)

        SliderDefaults.set(slider, defaults: defaults)

        if let valueFromDetauls = userDefaultsValue {
            slider.value = Float(valueFromDetauls)
        }

        saveValueInUserDefaults()
        updateLabel()
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can not set the value of a let property in swift, so please make them as var properties.